# What is the meaning of the word "this," all by itself?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, slang

I suppose this one might qualify as an internet meme, but I'm not sure.

I recently have begun seeing people use the word "this" as a single word sentence, such as in response to someone else's post. It seems like it might be a way of expressing agreement, but I am struck by how awkward it seems to me.

Unfortunately it's hard to search for anything about it, since it is such a common word.

What exactly does it mean, and where does it come from?

Comment: Can you add a link that shows an example? Or a screenshot?

Comment: @JasperLoy: Examples are given by the [top two Urban Dictionary definitions](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you'll usually see this is in religious, political, or technical disputes or polarizing comments. Someone will make an argument that is very polarizing and someone else will make a concise rebuttal that others see as completely decimating the original argument. To indicate their belief that the original point is fully rebutted and can now be rejected or placed in the proper context, they may reply simply, "this".

It is basically the usual meaning of *this* -- the thing I'm referring to (the rebuttal or response to the original point). As an exclamation, it indicates that the thing being referred to (whatever it's a reply or response to) is precisely what is necessary, appropriate, and/or correct. Think of it as short for, "this is what needed to be said", or "this is it".

Comment: This[.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65555/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-this-all-by-itself)

Comment: Another way of putting it is "I rest my case."

Answer (score 4):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=this)

> **this** - slang word used on internet forums meaning *"I agree with you 100%"* or *"that is very true"*.

Comment: And the top Urban Dictionary definition tells us it was used as early as 2007 and was commonly used on Fark.com.